# Teaching code the mathematical operation

Tags: javascript

So I want my code to learn the mathematical operation, firstly I implement the method calculate(str) that takes a string like "1 + 2" in the format "NUMBER operator NUMBER" and returns the result. at first it should understant + and minus -.
After this I need to add the method addOperator(name,func) that teaches the calculator a new operation. it takes the oparator name and the two-argument function func(a,b) that implements it.

```
    function Calculator(){
    this.calculate = function(str){
        this.str = str;
        let arr = this.str.split(" ");
        for (let item in arr) {
            if (arr[item] == '+'){
                return Number(arr[0]) + Number(arr[arr.length-1]);
            }
            else if (arr[item] == '-'){
                return Number(arr[0]) - Number(arr[arr.length-1]);
            }
        }
    }
    this.addOperator = function (name, func){
        this.name = name;
        this.func = function (){};
    }
}

let obj = new Calculator();
alert(obj.calculate(prompt("Enter")));

obj.addOperator("*", (a,b) => a * b);
obj.addOperator("/", (a,b) => a / b);
obj.addOperator("**", (a,b) => a ** b);

let result = obj.calculate("2 ** 3");
alert(result)
```

when I try to add the "**" operation I get undefined, I don't know how to make it learn it.

Comment: The `+` and `-` operators are hard-coded in the `calculate` function right now and `addOperator` doesn't do anything. What do you expect?

Comment: And `addOpperator` doesn't seem to do anything. It overwrites `name` and `func`, but those are never used. It also entirely ignores its `func` parameter.

Comment: I just need some advises on rearranging the code.

Answer (score 0):

I completely rearranged the code, so it looks like this

```
let operation = {
    "+": (a,b) => a+b,
    "-": (a,b) => a-b,
}

function Calculator(){
    this.calculate = function(str){
        this.str = str;
        let arr = this.str.split(" ");  // splits user's operation

        let a = Number(arr[0]);     // storing "number" members of an array in the variables
        let b = Number(arr[2]);

        for (let item in operation){        //iterating through global object 
            if (arr[1] == item){            // comparing the user's operation to objects key
                return operation[item](a,b);    // returning the function that is written in the value of objects key.
            }
        }
    }
    this.addOperator = function (name, func){
        operation[name] = func;             // adding the new operation to the "operation" object
    }
}

let obj = new Calculator();

alert(obj.calculate(prompt("Enter")));
obj.addOperator("*", (a,b) => a * b);
obj.addOperator("/", (a,b) => a / b);
obj.addOperator("**", (a,b) => a ** b);

let result = obj.calculate("5 ** 2");  
alert(result)   // output is 25
```

I created an object operation, that has "+" and "-" keys, that have the value of function which does the operation respectively, after this I changed the whole constructor ("Calculator"), so it could recognize user's input and after that depending on what operation user wants, I check the object for its key's and if it matches this function returns wanted function. 
Lastly, I modified the addOperator function, which adds keys and values, that are given to it, to the object "operation", so as a result it learned the new operation.

Comment: You should explain some of the changes and what fixes the original issue

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: I figured the answer on my own, so I have no questions left.